# Scope of Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have 2 snippets with unclear results

**This** is fine:

```
List<int> MemoryTest = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 100000).ToList(); 
Console.WriteLine("RAM: {0:0,0} KB", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024); //542KB
```

**This** is fine aswell (30KB appear to be the overhead from the Console)

```
List<int> MemoryTest = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 100000).ToList();
MemoryTest = null;   
Console.WriteLine("RAM: {0:0,0} KB", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024); //30KB
```

**Snippet (1)** Here I expect not 542KB, because the `List<int>` is out of scope

```
{
    List<int> MemoryTest = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 100000).ToList();             
}   
Console.WriteLine("RAM: {0:0,0} KB", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024); //542KB
```

**Snippet (2)** Even a `GC.Collect()` does not help:

```
{
    List<int> MemoryTest = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 100000).ToList();             
}
GC.Collect();    
Console.WriteLine("RAM: {0:0,0} KB", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024); //542KB
```

Why does my GarbageCollector / *Managed Code* not clear up RAM as expected?

Comment: It clears up RAM as I expect. You need to adjust your expectations :) Also,  don't run in a debugger, at all - that will hold locals as long as possible, to aid with debugging. Block scopes and explicit `= null` do not affect the lifetime of locals at all - the only thing that matters is whether the local is used in a possible code path or not. Finally `GC.Collect` isn't enough to force a garbage collection - it's more like a post-it note to the GC to do a collection sometimes soon, even if it doesn't seem to be necessary.